# Calculate AUC using predicted values and labels from a 5 fold classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, auc

I have a classifier for a binary problem. That has outputs between 0 and 1 for predictions for the two class A or B (for example sunny, not sunny). The classifier has ran on 5 unique folds of the data set and in each fold I have the outcome of the classifier as a value between 0 and 1 for each class, Class A (for example 0.83) and Class B (0.17). I also know the true label for that classification attempt.

For each fold I also have Cohen's Kappa, Weighted Cross Entropy, confusion matrix, Precision, Recall and F1.

Is there anyway to calculate the AUC or approximate it using the data I have at hand?

Many thanks, 
Mo

Comment: If the output is continuous, you are not using a classifier but rather something like a probability model.  And none of the measures you listed are proper accuracy scoring rules.  See [this](http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage) and [this](http://fharrell.com/post/classification).  And unless your sample size is huge you may need to do 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation to get adequate precision for model performance metrics.

Comment: Thanks for that Frank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the estimator

$$\widehat{AUC}_k = \frac{\sum_{i:y_i = B}\sum_{j:y_j = A}\mathcal{I}(\hat p^A_i < \hat p^A_j)}{\sum_{i:y_i = B}\sum_{j:y_j = A} 1},$$
where $\hat p^A_i$ is the predicted probability of observation $i$ belonging to class A,
computed for each of the $5$ folds, and then average these to get an estimate of the out of sample AUC as

$$\widehat{AUC} = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{k=1}^5\widehat{AUC}_k.$$

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, can I kindly ask what is "I" and what is the denominator of that fraction?

Comment: $\mathcal{I}$ is an indicator function, i.e., a function that is equal to 1 whenever
$\hat p_i^A < \hat p_j^A$, and 0 otherwise. The denominator is the sum over all the observations of both classes over the constant $1$. Which will be the number of observations that belong to class A times the number of observations  that belong to class B.